# Country Codes API

Tags: country-codes

I was able to construct a detailed spreadsheet from iso.org, by going through 10 different web pages, copying and pasting.

What I would like to do, is keep this list updated, and add/de-activate as countries appear, disappear or split.

I did a search, but could not find an API to retrieve the ISO codes (long name, 2-code, 3-code, numeric). Anyone aware of such an API?

Comment: It's been 10 years since the data changed, and another 18 years since the change before that. What problem would an API solve?

Comment: 1) this does not answer my question. 2) wouldn't be better to do it the right way - programmatically, as opposed to manually?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: Also, official amendments to ISO 3166 via Newsletters typically lag changes in national sovereignty by weeks or months. Not only would manual updates be simpler, they would probably be faster.

Comment: Might be better asked on the sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.